# Weird/Unexpected output in my map reduce job (1 extra output)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

So i am new in big data management and in hadoop ,but i cant understand my programm's behavior even with my java experience.
So first i am going to give my code and my input:
This is the mapper and reducer code.

```
public class builtdifferent {
    
public static class mybmapper extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    

        
    Text textKey = new Text();
    Text textValue = new Text();
  

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] field = line.split(",");
            
            String name = field[1];
            String games = field[8];
            String sex = field[2];
            String age = field[3];
            String team = field[6];
            String sport = field[12];
            String medal = field[field.length-1];
            int gold =0 ,silver = 0, bronze = 0;
            if (medal.equals("Gold")|| medal.equals("Silver") || medal.equals("Bronze") || medal.equals("0")) {
                    if (medal.equals("Gold"))
                        gold =1 ;
                    
                    if (medal.equals("Silver"))
                        silver =1 ;
                
                    if (medal.equals("Bronze"))
                        bronze =1 ;
            }   
            context.write(new Text(name + " " + games +  " " +  sex  ), new Text(age + "," + team + "," + sport + "," + gold + "," + silver + "," + bronze));

    }
} 

public static class mybreducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
     Text textValue = new Text();
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String team="",sport="", age="";
            //String test="",test2="";
            int mg=0,ms=0,mb=0,a=0;
            
            for (Text value : values) {
                String line = value.toString();
                String[] aif = line.split(",");
                if (aif.length < 6) {
                    context.write(key, value);
                    break;
                }
                age= String.valueOf(aif[0]);
                team = String.valueOf(aif[1]);
                sport = String.valueOf(aif[2]);
                mg+=Integer.valueOf(aif[3]);
                ms+=Integer.valueOf(aif[4]);
                mb+=Integer.valueOf(aif[5]);
            }
    
     a=mg+ms+mb;
     textValue.set(age + " " + team + " " + sport + " " + mg + " " + ms + " " + mb + " " + a);
     context.write(key,textValue);
     }
}
```

}

This is the main code.

```
  Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
      Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2, "best athletes");
      job2.setJarByClass(athletes.class);
      job2.setMapperClass(builtdifferent.mybmapper.class);
      job2.setCombinerClass(builtdifferent.mybreducer.class);
      job2.setReducerClass(builtdifferent.mybreducer.class);
      job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));
      System.exit(job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

So basically i have to process records of Olympic athletes of this type:
ID,Name,Sex,Age,Height,Weight,Team,NOC,Games,Year,Season,City,Sport,Event,Medal

This is 2 record examples:

3,GunnarNielsenAaby,M,24,0,0,Denmark,DEN,1920Summer,1920,Summer,Antwerpen,Football,Football Men's Football,0

4,Edgar Lindenau Aabye,M,34,0,0,Denmark/Sweden,DEN,1900 Summer,1900,Summer,Paris,Tug-Of-War,Tug-Of-War Men's Tug-Of-War,Gold

Each athlete has many entries and i need to count the medals and produce an output that looks like that:
Key(Name,Games,Sex)  Value(Age,Team,Sport,Gold,Silver,Bronze,ALL medals)

"Andrew William ""Andy"" Stanfield" 1952 Summer M   24 United States Athletics 2 0 0 2

Anyway my code works and i get the medals as i want but i also get one extra output(i need for each athlete 1 output for each game he participated,for example one for 1964 Summer and one for 1968 Summer.As you see i get 1 extra garbage line  with 4 zeros for each correct one).
This is an example of my output file(part-r-00000):

"Aagje ""Ada"" Kok (-van der Linden)" 1964 Summer F       17 Netherlands Swimming 0 2 0 2

"Aagje ""Ada"" Kok (-van der Linden)" 1964 Summer F       0 0 0 0

"Aagje ""Ada"" Kok (-van der Linden)" 1968 Summer F       21 Netherlands Swimming 1 0 0 1

"Aagje ""Ada"" Kok (-van der Linden)" 1968 Summer F    0 0 0 0

So as you can see after one correct output i get one  empty one with 4 zeros and other data missing.
I have 2 context.write methods in my reducer so i suspected one of them is wrong so if i delete `context.write(key, value);`  (inside the if) i get only the wrong output with (with 4 zeros i showed you)
and if i delete `context.write(key,textValue);` I get an empty output file. If i keep the both i get the "weird" output I showed you(which is correct but also wrong).
Also I get a  tab that separates the key and value in the output file

I tried to describe the problem the best i could , but i really don't get why and what it is happening, i wish i could explain it better
I really hope someone can help and if this is a bad question and it goes down, i would really like some feedback on how to ask better questions.
Thanks a lot in advance!!!!

Comment: This is an answer similar to what you are trying to achieve based on a similar olympic athlete's input data https://stackoverflow.com/a/65160408/5644037

Comment: Thank you very much ,i will check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer, i needed to add this `if(((LongWritable)key).get() == 0) {             return;         }`    at the beginning of the map function ,above  the `String line = value.toString();`   line.